# how to show total at listview's last index in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a list of transactions and i want to show total expense or balance at last index of listview..

I have taken expTotal for total Expense and i am initializing total before build method

its showing proper result when i have few datas but when i add more data and scroll listview, expTotal showing all time with some increments

and even if i place **int expTotal=0** inside widget build..its showing the same.

here is my code

```
int expTotal=0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
               Container(
                height: 400,
                 color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    itemCount: transactionList.length + 1,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                      if (index == transactionList.length) {
                        //ListTile for Total
                        return ListTile(
                          tileColor: Colors.grey,
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                          title: Center(child: Text('Total ')),
                          trailing: Text(expTotal.toString()),
                        );
                      }

                      final transactionModel = transactionList[index];

                      if(transactionModel.isExpense==true)
                        expTotal=expTotal+transactionModel.amount;
                      else
                        expTotal=expTotal-transactionModel.amount;

                      return ListTile(
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          child: Text(transactionModel.id),
                        ),
                        title: Text(transactionModel.category),
                        trailing: Text(
                          transactionModel.amount.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: transactionModel.isExpense
                                  ? Colors.red
                                  : Colors.blue),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This will only increase and decrease the expTotal value when the values scroll into view. You should calculate this total outside the builder

Comment: if i create a function outside of build, than giving result what i want but this function will be called whenever i scroll listview...is it good approach?

Comment: If you call that function only when you are in `if (index == transactionList.length) {` then it only calls that when that item scrolls into view. I gave an aswer which is sort of like that. Instead of a function making it a getter, which I think is cleaner in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
int expTotal=0;
```

you could write this to calculate it on the spot whenever you need it

```
int get expTotal =>
    transactionList.fold<int>(0, (value, element) =>
    element.isExpanse
        ? value + element.amount
        : value - element.amount);
```

Then you can leave out this part

```
if(transactionModel.isExpense==true)
  expTotal=expTotal+transactionModel.amount;
else
  expTotal=expTotal-transactionModel.amount;
```

and then it should work as expected while leaving the rest of the code the same

Comment: one more question rise in my mind...is it possible to make sum of only those items which are visible in listview...

Comment: Kind of yes but value will unpredictable because list view will also render some of the widgets which are not visible on screen, it's also not recommend to calculate things on scroll instead use pagination and then show total on top.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists):

> In contrast to the default ListView constructor, which requires
> creating all items at once, the ListView.builder() constructor creates
> items as they’re scrolled onto the screen.

Your code calculating expTotal expects the builder to pass through the list completely and only once, giving you an exact total, but in reality the builder is only building items that scroll onto the screen, so your expTotal is only triggered for a subset of the items that are displayed. Worse, if you scroll backwards and forwards, the visible elements would be counted in expTotal each time they are displayed.

It would be better to calculate the expTotal at the top of the build method, rather than inside the ListView.builder:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  int expTotal = 0;

  for (int i=0; i<transactionList.length; i++) {
    if(transactionModel.isExpense==true)
      expTotal=expTotal+transactionModel.amount;
    else
      expTotal=expTotal-transactionModel.amount;
  }

  return Scaffold
  .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you scroll through the list, the builder rebuilds widgets, and if you are performing calculations inside the builder, it can lead to incorrect results due to repeated calculations. You should calculate the total before building the list. Editing your provided code, you should have something similar to the below:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  int expTotal = transactionList.fold(0, (total, transaction) {
return transaction.isExpense
    ? total + transaction.amount
    : total - transaction.amount;
  });
    
  return Scaffold(
    // other things
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // Some other things
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                itemCount: transactionList.length + 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == transactionList.length) {
                    // list tile for total
                    return ListTile(
                      // others
                      trailing: Text(expTotal.toString()),
                    );
                  }

                  final transactionModel = transactionList[index];

                  // transaction tile
                  return ListTile(
                    // others
                    trailing: Text(
                      transactionModel.amount.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: transactionModel.isExpense
                              ? Colors.red
                              : Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

You could also move the computation from the `build` method to `initstate`.

```
int expTotal = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    expTotal = transactionList.fold(0, (total, transaction) {
      return transaction.isExpense
          ? total + transaction.amount
          : total - transaction.amount;
    });
  }
```